# Маленькая иконка на Meizu 16

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть приложение, для него делал иконки через ImageAsset что в AndroidStudio. Иконки сделаны из двух векторов (иконка и фон соответственно). На всех устройствах нормально, кроме (на данный момент) Meizu 16. Иконка в данном устройстве занимает только процентов 50-60 (такая маленькая, в середине "прям как моя зарплата":). Может кто сталкивался с данной проблемой?

И ещё вопрос, для чего нужна иконка: Full Bleed Layers? Я что-то из документации не догнал. Может ли эта иконка использоваться в лаунчерах на смартфонах в том числе и на указанном выше?

Comment: Да, с проблемой  маленькой зарплаты я сталкивался очень не приятно)) а, на счет иконки если у вас стоит тема то попробуйте ее убрать и возможно иконка изменится

Comment: Иконки других приложений нормальные (не исключино что они PNG), но проблема присудствует и это факт